# How to return JSON without Uniocde symbols using JsonModel in ZF2?

Tags: php, json, unicode, zend-framework2

I have an array of objects and I want to return it as JSON to the client's browser.

Code parsing the array to JSON is as follows:

```
public static function parse(array $data){

    $parsed = array();

    foreach ($data as $entity){
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
        $arrayObject = array();

        foreach($reflection->getProperties() as $property){
            $property->setAccessible(true);
            $arrayObject[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($entity);
            $property->setAccessible(false);
        }

        array_push($parsed, $arrayObject);
    }

    $parsed = json_encode($parsed);


    return $parsed;
}
```

I'am using this static method, because simple casting an object to an array gives me null bytes keys when proporties aren't public. Until now everything is ok and I'm trying to return parsed array with JsonModel.

```
return new JsonModel(
    array(
        'data' => ObjectToJsonParser::parse($match)
    ));
```

In the Firebug I receive correct JSON response, but the content is wrong having Unicodes symbols.

[image]How can I correctly return JSON without these Unicode symbols?

Answer (score 0):

If you're encoding unicode characters, you should use [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/json_encode) option when calling `json_encode` in your `parse` function.

Just like this :

```
$parsed = json_encode($parsed, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

And you could use this to return the response without using `JsonModel` :

```
return $this->getResponse()->setContent(ObjectToJsonParser::parse($match));
```

Comment: I would like to mention that, my parse function returns data correctly (tested withuout ZF2 JsonModel . The problem is that the JsonModel encodes it wrong.

Comment: `JsonModel` encodes the array after you encoded it with that function. Try to return the Json using `$this->getResponse()->setContent()`. See my edit.

Comment: I did it like you said and additionally set content-type to application/json and it's ok. But I want to know is it possible for somehow to configure returned JsonModel to work properly?

Comment: @czeski `JsonModel` can't escape unicode characters. You could create custom `MyJsonModel` which extends the `JsonModel` class and override the `serialize()` method but I don't think it's good thing.